# Processing an Order: Save recipient address, or reference by lastInsertId()?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm developing an e-cart/shop with PHP/MySQL.

I had decided from the beginning to have a separate table for addresses so that I would not store duplicate data (for example, every time an order is made to the same address, the order would store the address_id rather than door, street, town, city, post_code, etc.

Now I'm making the query to process an Order, I'm going to have an option for the user to
a) select an address from a stored list (of customer_id, address_id) -or-
b) create a new address (the query returns the lastInsertId() ).

I'm having doubts because I'm not sure if there are any situations where the `lastInsertId()` would return the wrong `address_id` and so the system would send the order to the wrong, stored address? Or when the order is processed a wrong id number is passed through?

What extra steps can I take to make such a system fool-proof so that the wrong address is never given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client executed.

See more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: +1 Wow I had never even thought about that - but its a relief it is unique. So do you think my process is perfectly safe?

Comment: I wouldn't say *that*, but I don't see any outstanding issues :)